# Logo layout problem, how to make it static even if the windows was resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ask you guys, I tried coding my logo, the logo format should be straight, but I found a problem, when the window resizes when the logo time is not straight but it will go down, so it overlaps.

Here is a picture from my website and what's the problem with my logo format?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTnle.jpg (logo problem)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypvu6.jpg (website overview with problem)

following my HTML code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>AN Photography | Photos</title>

  <!-- add icon link -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/Icons/unnamed.png" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300i,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/icomoon/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightgallery.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="site-wrap">

    <div class="site-mobile-menu">
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
        <div class="site-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
          <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
    </div>



    <header class="site-navbar py-3 border-bottom" role="banner">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">

          <div class="col-6 col-xl-2" data-aos="fade-down">
            <h1 class="mb-0"><a href="index.html" class="text-black h2 mb-0">AN | Photos</a></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10 col-md-8 d-none d-xl-block" data-aos="fade-down">
            <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right text-lg-center" role="navigation">

              <ul class="site-menu js-clone-nav mx-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a>|</a></li>
                <li><a href="Photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a>|</a></li>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a href="#">More</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">My Journal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../newsletter/newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>|</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6 col-xl-2 text-right" data-aos="fade-down">
            <div class="d-none d-xl-inline-block">
              <ul class="site-menu js-clone-nav ml-auto list-unstyled d-flex text-right mb-0" data-class="social">
                <li>
                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/stevenWilliamG" class="pl-0 pr-3"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/AdrikAleandra" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/audynaufal7/" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-instagram"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/audy-naufal-ghiffari-ceh-875072141/" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="d-inline-block d-xl-none ml-md-0 mr-auto py-3" style="position: relative; top: 3px;"><a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </header>



  <div class="site-section"  data-aos="fade">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-12 ">
              <h2 class="site-section-heading text-center">Photo Gallery</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row" id="lightgallery">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_1.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Sunrise Point Cukul</h4><p>Popular vista point offering scenic views of the sun rising over green hills with tea plantations.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_1.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_2.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Kampung Cai Ranca Upas</h4><p>Rustic mountainside tent campground with a hot-spring pool, outdoor activities & deer.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_2.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_3.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bandung</h4><p>Bandung is not just a geographical problem, for me, it also involves feelings.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_3.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_4.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Lembang</h4><p>A Mountainous Getaway from the Hectic Urban Life.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_4.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_5.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Situ Cukul</h4><p>One of the hidden gems that must be visited by travelers in Bandung!</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_5.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_6.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Kampung Cai Ranca Upas</h4><p>Good place to have fun with family and friends. Camping place that have lots of surprising unexpected Views.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_6.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_7.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Singkur Village</h4><p>A tourist destination in the Pangalengan area that offers exotic nature tourism with the nuances of the village, Kampung Singkur.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_7.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_8.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Situ Gunung</h4><p>Best place for photo hunting in Sukabumi.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_8.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_9.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Putri Mountain</h4><p>Excellent suited place for artists and connoisseurs of the authenticity of nature.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_9.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_10.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bumi Pasundan</h4><p>MAW Brouwer: “ Bumi Pasundan Lahir Ketika Tuhan Sedang Tersenyum”</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_10.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_11.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Parangtritis Beach</h4><p>Parangtritis, a Mystical and Enchanting Beach in Yogyakarta.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_11.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_12.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Imogiri Pine Forest</h4><p>Of shady pine trees and a magical scenery — Imogiri Pine Forest located in south Yogyakarta offers every visitor a fairytale moment of their own.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_12.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_13.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Imogiri Pine Forest</h4><p>one of nice destination while travelling in Yogyakarta.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_13.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_14.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Nglinggo Tea Plantation</h4><p>Wonderful break outside the city.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_14.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_15.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Waduk Sermo</h4><p>Large artificial lake drawing visitors with sunset views & boat rides, plus fishing & cycling.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_15.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_16.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Slili Beach</h4><p>Slili Beach, Mount Kidul Jogja: Tiny Beach Between Two Hills</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_16.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_17.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Embung Tambakboyo</h4><p>Sunset viewing & photography are popular at this sizable dam with a jogging track.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_17.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_18.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Embung Nglanggeran</h4><p>Picturesque lake on a volcanic mountain used to collect rainwater for nearby fruit orchards.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_18.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_19.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Parangtritis Beach</h4><p>According to legend, the Javanese will advise you and even themselves not wear green, especially yellow-green around the beach as it’s believed that this attracts the Queen.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_19.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_20.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Timang Beach</h4><p>Worth every penny, effort and fear!</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_20.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_21.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Mount Gede Pangrango National Park</h4><p>Diverse Nature in Gunung Gede Pangrango National Park, Indonesia.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_21.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_22.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bogor</h4><p>“Adopt the pace of nature. Her secret is patience.”</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_22.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_23.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Cipanas</h4><p>Away from Cibodas, and further down the road is the town of Cipanas. Here is the Cipanas Palace, the President’s mountain residence set amidst manicured lawns and refreshing hot springs.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_23.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_24.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bogor Botanical Gardens</h4><p>Bogor Botanical Garden, Stroll at Leisure to Admire the Variety of Old, Gnarled Trees.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_24.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_25.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Shinjuku Gyoen</h4><p>Spacious city park in Shinjuku.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_25.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_26.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Osaka Castle (Osakajo)</h4><p>Reconstruction of the large castle.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_26.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_27.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Kyoto</h4><p>“The peace within and flowing from sacred spaces and architecture places is clothed in forgiveness, renunciation, and reconciliation.”</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_27.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_28.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Byodoin Temple</h4><p>Temple with a beautiful Pure Land Garden.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_28.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_29.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Arashiyama Bamboo Grove</h4><p>The Arashiyama Bamboo Grove is one of Kyoto’s top sights and for good reason: standing amid these soaring stalks of bamboo is like being in another world.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_29.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_30.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Sanzenin Temple</h4><p>Popular Temple in rural Ohara north of Kyoto.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_30.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_31.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Koshoji Temple</h4><p>Zen temple on the other side of the river.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_31.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_32.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Kinkakuji (Golden Pavilion)</h4><p>Temple building covered in gold.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_32.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_33.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Hakone Shrine</h4><p>Hakone’s most famous Shinto shrine.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_33.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_34.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Arashiyama Bamboo Grove</h4><p>“Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything better.”</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_34.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_35.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Jamia Mosque</h4><p>The Jamia Mosque, an Unexpected Oasis in Central Hong Kong.</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_35.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 item" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/big-images/nature_big_36.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Hong Kong</h4><p>“Never let your memories be greater than your dreams.”</p>">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/nature_small_36.jpg" alt="IMage" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer py-4">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <p>
        © 2020 Audy Naufal <a>|</a> &nbsp <a href="about.html" style="color:rgb(169,169,169);">About</a> &nbsp <a href="contact.html" style="color:rgb(169,169,169);">Contact</a> &nbsp <a href="#" style="color:rgb(169,169,169);">Feedback</a> &nbsp <a href="../newsletter/newsletter.html" style="color:rgb(169,169,169);">Newsletter</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>





  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/aos.js"></script>

  <script src="js/picturefill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

P.S:

Please don't block me since i'm new to this plaform and i need to ask a question

Comment: do you have the actual web page?

Comment: https://staging-anphotography.azurewebsites.net/web%20development/main/Photos.html (Staging phase)

Answer (score 0):

That is because the width of your logo column is not longer fit for smaller screen size. That is why your logo wrap to next line. Increase the col should fix this.

```
<!-- change col-6 to col-9 -->
<div class="col-9 col-xl-2" data-aos="fade-down">
  <h1 class="mb-0"><a href="index.html" class="text-black h2 mb-0">AN | Photos</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="col-10 col-md-8 d-none d-xl-block" data-aos="fade-down">
... <!-- no change for this -->
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-xl-2 text-right" data-aos="fade-down">
... <!-- change col-6 to col-3 -->
</div>
```